# "This feature is not available in a portable workstation environment." error

Tags: windows-10, backup, disk-cloning, windows-to-go

After cloning Windows 10 to an SSD, Windows 10 keeps opening dialog boxes with the message "This feature is not available in a portable workstation environment".

They also appear when I try to use "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" or change any option.

I've tried several suggestions but to no avail ([1](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-error-al-realizar-copias-de-seguridad/2141622c-6007-4e04-bea5-50d29e84f6e5?auth=1))([2](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-mensaje-autom%C3%A1tico-copias-de/36819fb1-bc64-4af5-8b5b-fd80d8c7fdbb))([3](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/activar-las-copias-de-seguridad-en-windows-10-en/90f23862-ba67-479b-b98f-6ef735ac3e6f)).

What didn't work:

- Disabling Windows Backup Service (SDRSVC) and restarting.
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`
- `sfc /scannow`
- Looking for malware.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, this behavior is due to connecting the old drive thru a USB disk case after booting the cloned one. Maybe a signature disk collision, that Windows 10 resolves identifying the system as "Windows To Go", hence portable.

Finally, I found [a page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/windows-10-thinks-its-a-portable-workstation/04b7e67d-3b3e-4116-823f-9d29e9bf5f27) that referenced [a page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/f889f826-4f9b-45d9-a88b-2f8cff2a1cb1/quotthis-feature-is-not-available-in-a-portable-workstation-environmentquot?forum=w8itprogeneral) that referenced [a page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/af05f60a-4cb0-4561-b49f-71938dad6853/my-computer-thinks-its-a-windows-to-go-computer-but-its-not?forum=W8ITProWTG) that referenced [the solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2778881/multiple-operations-fail-if-windows-8-is-improperly-identified-as-a-wi).

You must change certain registry value. You can open `regedit.exe` and navigate to the proper value or just run, as admin:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PortableOperatingSystem /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```